# How to compare string with array in XSLT1.0 in apply templates

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, exslt

Suppose,
if I have `"Test1|Test2|Test3"` as a string
and
I want compare it with following:

```
<items>
<item>Test1</item>
<item>Test2</item>
<item>Test3</item>
</items>
```

Is it possible to check in apply template is it true of false?

Thanks

Comment: Suppose I have string Test1

It should match only

<Items>
<Item>Test1</Item>
</Items>

Suppose I have string Test1|Test2

It should match only
<Items>
<Item>Test1</Item>
<Item>Test2</Item>
</Items>

Suppose I have string Test1|Test2|Test3

It should match only
<Items>
<Item>Test1</Item>
<Item>Test2</Item>
<Item>Test3</Item>
</Items>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you take precaution and use:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="item[contains(concat('|', $yourString, '|'), concat('|', ., '|'))]"/>
```

Otherwise you may get false positives - for example, if your string is:

```
Test1|Test25|Test301
```

a simple `contains()` test will also pass all of these:

```
<item>Test2</item>
<item>Test3</item>
<item>Test30</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
  <xsl:variable name="arrayString" select="'Test1|Test2|Test3'"/>

  <xsl:template match="items">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="item[contains($arrayString,.)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('Template_item : ', .)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Mvnt3H

Comment: Thanks for your time. But contains will be return true if we send Test1|Test2 or Test1 also. Need All matched then only true. If I send from string Test1, then check if there is only one matching item.

Comment: See @michael.hor257k answer below.